# Google Plus API Nuget Package

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, google-plus, nuget-package

I need to create posts, etc through my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

Does anyone know decent library for **Google Plus API**? *(Preferable as a NuGet package).*

Comment: "post updates, etc"? Please clarify.

Comment: I mean create google plus posts and so on

Comment: so please update your question with this info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no publicly documented API that lets you automatically post to your Google+ page or stream.

There is an API that HootSuite is currently using that is slowly opening up to other vendors. See https://plus.google.com/u/0/104946722942277428266/posts/LUi2ZNyRHag for more information about what is coming and how you can sign up to request access to this. This is expected to allow you to post to a Google+ Page.

There is also the "Google+ History API" that is currently in developer preview which will allow you to create moments for a user, but they would need to manually share these moments on their stream if they choose to do so. See https://developers.google.com/+/history/ for further details.